# Copy to Sharepoint workflow does not run correctly automatically

Tags: sharepoint, copy, workflow

I have an InfoPath form I need to publish to a folder within a document library in Sharepoint 2010. I set up a workflow using Copy to Sharepoint and it points to the proper folder. It’s supposed to copy the form to a folder and then delete it from the current location. 
The workflow runs fine manually, but NOT automatically.  When it’s set to run automatically, it does not copy the file, just deletes it. 
I have the Workflow Settings to not Start Manually, and Start When New Items are Created. 
Anything else I’m missing?   Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that content types are identical in source and destination, try the following trick:

Add a "pause" action for 1 minute before the "copy" step in the workflow and this should fix your issue.